# Auto Login Issue in React-native IOS &Android

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am developing a sample application with React Native. My issue is that I am getting login credentials saved in `localstorage()` async storage in login page that values getting in `index.ios.js` file but values shows null.

Any one please tell me, when I login to page `go_to_main`, after that shows `login` screen and after main screen This is my main issue

Show can I get the values in `index.ios.js` file. Here is my code:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  AsyncStorage,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import NavigationExperimental from 'react-native-deprecated-custom-components';
var loginScene //= require('./src/bundles/Login/scenes/LoginScene/index.js');
var SplashScreen = require('@remobile/react-native-splashscreen');

 class SampleApp extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          email:'',
          userName:''

        }
     }

     componentWillMount() {


        AsyncStorage.getItem('Email',(err,Email)=>{
          if(Email == null ){

          }
          else{
            AsyncStorage.getItem('userName',(err,userName)=>{
              if(userName == null ){

                }
                else{
                  this.setState({
                    email:Email,
                    userName:userName
                  })
                }

            }).done() 
          }
          }).done() 
    }

  render() {
    if(this.state.email  != null){

       loginScene = require('./src/bundles/Dashboard/scenes/koopiMainScene/index.js');
    }
    else{
      alert("email1111:"+this.state.email)
      loginScene = require('./src/bundles/Login/scenes/LoginScene/index.js');

    }
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:'white'}}>
            <NavigationExperimental.Navigator
              initialRoute={{
                 component:loginScene,
                 passProps:{menuTitle:this.state.userName, Email:this.state.email}
               }}
                 configureScene={(route) => ({
                    ...NavigationExperimental.Navigator.SceneConfigs.HorizontalSwipeJump,
                    gestures: false
                  })}
                 renderScene={(route, navigator) =>{
                   return <route.component navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps} />;
                 }}/>

        </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () =>SampleApp);
```

Comment: Please edit your question. I have corrected your spelling and grammar mistake as it was possible. Do not start each word with capital letter.

Comment: Just trying to better understand your question, you are wanting to show the login screen if the user is null?

Comment: But Value is there showing Null

Answer (score 0):

I don'nt see your code where you are storing the value in the localstorage 
so according to my View you can this way to store and get value form localstorage

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(email));
```

and for getting data you should use the parse method

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('user', (err, result) => {
  const usermail = JSON.parse(result);
  console.log(useremail)
});
```

By this type you would not get your value 
may be this can help you

Comment: Thanks for your Response, actually When I was Login in this Screen set AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(email)); alerady I set, After that I ma Using this in Starting page I am Fetching in componentWillmount() method.

Comment: which value is showing null , for username or email , let me know i can help with this

Comment: email Only Please Check it Once my above Code

Comment: did you used the parse for getting the value have do it
const usermail = JSON.parse(Email);

Comment: Dear @ashutoshPandey , I get Both Values But How Can i write Auto Login Procedure Index.ios.js file

Comment: Above My Code not Work in passProps Values not Passing Can you Check it Once

Comment: componentWillMount(){
      this.getUser();
      this.getuserName();
     }

     getUser(){
      AsyncStorage.getItem('Email', (err, result) => {
        this.state.usermail = result;
         email =this.state.usermail
        console.log("e:"+email)
      });
     }

     getuserName(){
      AsyncStorage.getItem('userName',(err, userName)=>{
        this.state.userName = userName;
        title = this.state.userName;
        console.log("t:"+title)
      });
     }

Comment: Those Two Values Not Get in render() method

Comment: in render() method null values above email and title undefined